# Can I Install Ubuntu as Dual Boot Without Partitioning the Hard Drive on Which I will Install it?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I'm trying to install Ubuntu to dual boot with Windows 10. I want to install it on my hard drive, which is not the SSD that my Windows 10 is installed on.

However, when I go to make a partition for my F: drive, there is no available space to shrink the drive, despite the fact that there is like 200 unused GB on it. I tried using GParted but its not working with my BIOS (gives me an error with secure boot, which I can't seem to turn off).

So, does it matter if I can't partition a bit of my F: drive? Will that be taken care of when I install Ubuntu alongside Windows?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)**  If you give more info like a `gparted --list` into your question, we can give a more informed answer.

Comment: I don't even get into gparted. I get a big red error that says "SECURE BOOT VIOLATION. THE SYSTEM FOUND UNAUTHORIZED CHANGES ON THE FIRMWARE." Then it bumps me to the next thing in the boot order. I tried to turn off secure boot in bios.... but it's grayed out and I can't disable it.

Comment: Contact the manufacturer is the only thing I can say: this is a problem outside of Ubuntu and has to be resolved before you can install...

Comment: yes, you can use wubiuefi

Answer (score 1):

You certainly need a separate partition to install, if you don't want your data on the selected partition wiped.  When installed Ubuntu will be able to mount the other partitions and read data of them.

You don't need linux or other non-native windows tools to recover free space for a partition.  Use Windows tool for partition, then when you boot with the Ubuntu Installation media (CD or USB), Ubuntu will recognize the partition and prompt you to select whether to install on the free partition or wipe over the Windows partition.
This is an outline, can't give exact directions because I dual-booted my computers starting with Windows 7, not 10.  Win7 has the Disk Management tool built in.
From what I read Win10 has the same tool - [Check this page](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/best-free-partition-manager-for-windows-10.html) for the built-in tool and additional 9 options. It's a very plain task, I suggest use the built-in Microsoft tool. To find the tool type "Partition" or "Disk Management" at Windows Search.

Do not bother formatting the freed space or anything, just leave the free space.  Ubuntu Installation will take it from there.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That answered the main question, and means I have to solve this bigger problem. When I go to shrink the size of the partition, I can't reduce it to anything smaller than the whole drive, which is where the issue arises. According to disk manager, theres 0 space left to put the new partition in, despite the fact that there is clearly free space on the drive.

Comment: Some third party software seems to be able to do this. Whats the difference between windows and this software that windows cant do it and this software cant?

Comment: The likely cause is that your free space is fragmented in several segments, and not in a whole bunch at the end.  Defrag is the way to combine free space.  Probably the third party does just that.  With Windows built in utilities, you would need to run defrag first. If my replies answer your comment, please mark the answer (up arrow) - Ty

Comment: Max, do not use defrag if your disk is SSD, at least you need to check, there are some limitations with Solid State drives.  Btw : what is your total disk space? what is your free space? what is the size you intend to allot to Ubuntu?

Comment: I ended up just using this free partitioning tool, which seems to have worked: http://www.partition-tool.com/landing/home-download.htm. Thank you for your help everyone, now wondering if I can format "Partition #3 of SCSI2, Partition #4 of SCSI2, and Partition #5 of SCSI2" in the Ubunutu boot without losing my data.